# How do I print a KendoUI Widget(BarCode) with a custom page size?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a VERY simple little web app that has some fields that I generate a barcode from using KendoUI's Barcode like so:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Barcode().Name("myLabel").Value("SomeNumbersUserEntered").Encoding(BarcodeSymbology.Code39).Width(300).Height(100))
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I set the print page size to 4x6.

Am I over thinking this...If the printer can only print 4x6 then this would actually just need to be full page....

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with printing you can override the CSS specially for printing like explained **[here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)**. However if you want to override the Barcode width and height, then you will have to specify them not through the options but again with CSS (other way they are with heigher precendece).

Check the following example in both PrintPreview and Normal mode.

```
<span id="manchego"></span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#manchego").kendoBarcode({
            value: "2346722",
            type: "ean8"            
        });

    });
</script>
<style scoped>

   #manchego canvas{
       width: 500px;
       height: 500px;
   }

    @media print{
        #manchego canvas{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
         }  
    }           
</style>
```